# CPU speed much lower than base speed

Tags: windows-10, cpu, performance, bios

My computer has been slow for quite a while now even while performing basic tasks such as web browsing (to the point where simply typing into a search bar can take several seconds before the computer shows me that I've typed anything) and I've finally gotten around to trying to search for a solution.  I noticed that the speed listed on the performance tab of task manager is significantly lower than the base speed listed there (0.78GHz vs 2.59GHz) [See here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1A7zb.png)  I suspect that this may be largely what is causing my problems.

I have tried the following things to bring this speed closer to my base speed:

- Moving the power management slider to "Best performance" [See here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hTSbo.png)
- Increased the minimum processor state when plugged in to 100% [See here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TiG7I.png)
- Turned off Speedstep in my Bios (which is described in the BIOS as forcing my CPU into its maximum performance mode
- Turned off C-states in my BIOS which is described in the BIOS as allowing the processor to be put in other performance modes

Notably I have been trying the fixes recommended in this thread: [Maximum Processor Speed Lower Than It Should Be](https://superuser.com/questions/825721/maximum-processor-speed-lower-than-it-should-be)

Any advice on steps I can take short of reinstalling Windows is greatly appreciated!

System details:
Dell Latitude E7450
Intel Core i5-4310U CPU @ 2.00GHz   2.59GHz
8.00GB RAM
64-bit OS and processor

Comment: Try check if the Intel Thermal Driver exist in Device manager

Comment: I see ACPI thermal zone in device manager.  Checking coretemp as well, I see the cores are running in the high 40s celcius (46-49 degrees)

Answer (score 0):

Intel CPUs hace thermal management built in, which means if they get to hot they slow down to protect themselves. Check that the heatsink is clean and the fan is spinning freely.

Before.contemplating reinstalling Windows you may want to try booting a Linux based pendriv, putting the system under load (eg running a pi calculator)  and using cat /proc/cpuinfo to see the frequency of the CPU cores to work out if its hardware or software.

Comment: I used some compressed air to clean the vents on the computer.  Checking the coretemp utility, the cores are running around high 40s low 50s celsius.  The frequency per this utility is 798.15MHz (99.77 x 8.0) for both cores.

Comment: Good. Were you running a program to stress the CPU at the time? (if it was idle it would not increase the core frequency)

Comment: at the time of that reading, no.  I also tried some activities of various intensity but nothing impacted the speed, except for one second while playing a game, when I got the processor to spike to about 2GHz, so at least it seems the processor is capable of hitting a higher speed.  The activities i tried included the gaming (I don't have any particularly demanding games, I downloaded a game "sniper fury" from the windows store for this purpose), watching videos, and encoding a video (which worked my GPU hard but seemingly not so much my CPU).

Comment: Download and run prime95 to Load yur CPU.

Comment: ran it for about 10 hours, no errors no warnings.  The processor jumped up to 2.6GHz a couple of times or between 0.8 and 2.6 a couple of times, but only just for a second.  Still hovering at 0.78 the vast majority of the time (obviously I wasn't watching it the whole time, but I did watch it for a good 15 minutes at the start, and 5 min at the end).